# Wallet Pass & Push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wallet

I'm working on Wallet Pass & faced with the problem - Pass is not updated on sending push notification to ANPS.

In the same time when the Pass is updated manually (pull to update or switch auto updates on-off). So my Web service works and available.

I'v read even every post on this case i do:

1. Use the same certificate to sign pass & to send push with APNS
2. I do use pushToken from registration  payload
3. I do set Last-Updated header in downloading the latest pass from web service
4. I do see no errors in /v1/Log web service method

What can I miss else?
Or are there any way to trace pushes and see are they delivered to the phone or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I'v used obsolete binary protocol, instead of HTTP/2.
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/923